# OS Open Source data tif files

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I'm a new QGIS user and am having trouble adding tif files from OS VectorMap
District. 
I get them on to the map but they always appear in the bottom left hand corner, which I would guess indicates a CRS discrepancy. However, I have adjusted this so all layers are using OSGB 1936/BNG EPSG:27700, but nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @KRickard! Did you resave the layers with the new CRS (using **Save As...**) or did you use the **Set Layer CRS** option? Ideally, it's best to resave the layer with the new CRS.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you copy the .tfw files into the same directory as the tif files.

These store the georeferencing information, but are usually supplied by the OS in a separate folder, since they also supply .tab files for MapInfo.

If they are in the same folder and with the same name as the tif file QGIS will automatically find them.